# border-color and box-shadow color don't change after I change css code

Tags: html, css, angular, antd

I import a nz-date-picker, and I want to change the border color and box-shadow color when mouse hover and focus on the date-picker element, I change the color in the css class of the element, but doesnt work

I import ng-zorro-antd module in my component, and nz-date-picker works ok, then I open F12 to find the class of the nz-date-picker element, and override it in my component scss file,but it doesnt work, I override .ant-calendar-picker and .ant-calendar-picker-input, not working. Maybe I override the wrong class, but .ant-calendar-picker and .ant-calendar-picker-input are what I can find on the F12 dev-tool console.

my scss code:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .ant-calendar-picker {
    .ant-calendar-picker-input {
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        border-color: $primary-red;
        box-shadow: none;

      }
    }

  }
}
```

or like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .ant-calendar-picker {
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        border-color: $primary-red;
        box-shadow: none;

      }

  }
}
```

I can see my css code really exits on the chrome element console, but I dont know why it didn't work

this is working, but not helpful:

```
.ant-input {
  &:hover {
    border-color: $primary-red;
  }

  &:focus {
    border-color: $primary-red;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

I expect that the border color and box shadow color can change when mouse hover and focus on the nz-date-picker element
[image]

Comment: add `!important` to all overriding CSS

Comment: You are using Bootstrap and there are default styling for all elements. You need to override Bootstrap CSS. If it's possible please share your complete code. Thanks

Comment: please add jsfiddle link

Comment: add !important fix it, thanks

Comment: I guess somewhere in the source code of ng-zorro-antd have a higher css priority, and add !important overrides it, thanks for your idea

Comment: I will try jsfiddle next time if its not too complicated, And we're not using bootstrap, just ng-zorro-antd.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change Css when you hover on element, at first that element must have this style and then you change it when you hover it. for example:

```
.foo{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

and then

```
.foo:hover{
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: yes, but that's not my problem. I fix my problem with adding `!important` to the css code